# Showing that $\langle T(u),T(v)\rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$ implies $T$ is a linear isometry

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, isometry

Let $T$ belong to $\mathcal{L}(H)$ (i.e., the set of linear operators from $H \mapsto H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space).

I need to show that $T$ is an isometry iff $\langle T(u),T(v) \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$ for all $u,v \in H$.

I have been successfully able to show that if $T$ is an isometry, then $\langle T(u), T(v) \rangle=\langle u, v \rangle $:

> Suppose that $T$ is an isometry; i.e., that $\forall w \in H$, $||T(w)||=||w||$.
>
> Then, of course we have that $||T(w)||^{2} = ||w||^{2}$.
>
> Now, consider $u+v \in H$. Then, since $T$ is an isometry, $||T(u+v)||^{2} = ||u+v||^{2}$ implies that $\langle T(u+v),T(u+v) \rangle = \langle u + v, u+v \rangle \implies \langle T(u), T(u+v)\rangle + \langle T(v), T(u+v)\rangle = \langle u,u+v \rangle + \langle v, u+v \rangle \implies \langle T(u), T(u) \rangle + \langle T(u), T(v) \rangle + \langle T(v), T(u) \rangle + \langle T(v), T(v) \rangle = \langle u, u \rangle +  \langle u, v \rangle + \langle v, u \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle \implies \langle T(u), T(u) \rangle + \langle T(u), T(v) \rangle + \langle T(u), T(v) \rangle + \langle T(v), T(v) \rangle = \langle u, u \rangle +  \langle u, v \rangle + \langle u, v \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle \implies \langle T(u), T(u) \rangle + 2\langle T(u), T(v) \rangle + \langle T(v), T(v) \rangle = \langle u, u \rangle +  2\langle u, v \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle \implies ||T(u)||^{2} + 2\langle T(u),T(v) \rangle + ||T(v)||^{2} = ||u||^{2} + 2\langle u,v \rangle + ||v||^{2}$.
>
> Then, because $T$ is an isometry, $||T(u)||=||u|| \implies ||T(u)||^{2} = ||u||^{2}$ and $||T(v)||=||v|| \implies ||T(v)||^{2} = ||v||^{2}$, we have that
>
> $2\langle T(u),T(v) \rangle = 2\langle u,v \rangle \implies \langle T(u),T(v) \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle$.

I am having difficulty showing the other direction without using the thing I am trying to prove! Everywhere I've looked has said this direction is "obvious", which, although it might be true to those more knowledgeable than I, is meaningless to me.

Short of telling me this is "obvious" or "directly follows from" something without explaining in detail why, could someone please help me show the $\langle T(u), T(v) \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle \implies \, T\,\text{is an isometry}$ direction? Thank you.

Also, I understand that a lot of books give this as the definition of what it means to be an isometry; however, it is not. It's something that needs to be proven. The definition of isometry I am assuming as a basic principle here is $\forall w \in H$, $||T(w)||=||w||$.

And please refrain from snarkiness. Sometimes I have trouble with very simple things, even though very complicated things come easy to me. Please try to understand that not everybody's brain works the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\langle Tw, Tw\rangle=\langle w, w\rangle$. Taking $w=u-v$ gives $\langle T(u-v),T(u-v)\rangle=\langle(u-v),(u-v)\rangle\implies \left| u-v\right|^2=\left|Tu-Tv\right|^2$

Comment: All you need is the first sentence...

Comment: Comepletely true but the asker wanted it to be compeltely explicit, this shows why the first sentence gives you the definition of isometry.

Comment: I guess my point was that the inner product gives you a norm here right? No need to introduce the $u-v$

Comment: It is helpful to show how the "distance" between two vectors will be preserved. No need to keep arguing the point I already admitted that it's completely true that all you need it the first sentence.

Comment: Ok I see your point. Sorry, I thought you were using the definition of isometry as distance preserving.

Comment: @TonyS.F., and it would be just as legit if you took $w = u + v$?

Comment: Yes, because $u+v$ is a vector in the space we are in and $\langle Tw, Tw\rangle=\langle w,w\rangle$ holds for any such vector.